# Creating Forms using HMVC codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, forms, hmvc

I am trying to create a form using HMVC in codeigniter but it is showing `Fatal error: Call to undefined function form_open()` error
I included Controller.php , Modules.php and MY_Router.php in application/library folder, again it is showing error.. 
here is my code:-
for controller :-

```
<?php
class First extends MX_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

?>

for view :-

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1> hey this is first module.. </h1>
    <?php

        echo form_open('first/login');
        echo form_input('username',username);
        echo form_password('password',password);
        echo form_submit('Login',submit);
        form_close();

    ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the form helper:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

Comment: Thanks :)
Is there any other method to do that?

`<html>
 <body>
 <h1> hey this is first module.. </h1>

        <?php
            $this->load->helper('form');
            echo form_open('first_module/first/login');
            echo form_input('username',set_value('firstname','firstname'));
            echo form_password('password',set_value('firstname','firstname'));
            echo form_submit('submit','Login');
            form_close();

        ?>
    </body>
</html>`

Comment: I am actually asking that I am doing this :- `form_open('first_module/first/login');` Is this the right method to do that..?

Comment: Again another problem with data insertion in database :(